# How to phrase a proof of a equivalence relation of bijection

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

Define $\sim_\mathrm{bi}$ by
$$\sim_\mathrm{bi} = \{(S_1,S_2)\mid \text{there is a bijection } f:S_1 \to S_2\}$$
for $S_1,S_2 \subseteq \mathbb{N}$

My proof comes as:
In order to prove that $\sim_\mathrm{bi}$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathcal{P}(N)$, we should prove that the relation is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.

Reflexive: For all $S_1 \subseteq \mathcal{P}(N)$, then the identity function provides a bijection from $S_1$ to $S_1 \subseteq \mathcal{P}(N)$, so the relation is reflexive.

Symmetric: For $S_1 \subseteq \mathcal{P}(N)$, if $S_1 \sim_\mathrm{bi} S_2$, then there is a bijection $f: S_1 \to \S_2$, so there is a bijection $f^{-1} : S_2 \to S_1$, so $S_2 \sim_\mathrm{bi} S_1$, so the relation is symmetric.

Transitive: Assume that $S_1 \sim_\mathrm{bi} S_2$ and $S_2 \sim_\mathrm{bi} S_3$, then we know that there are bijections $f: S_1 \to S_2$ and $g: S_2 \to S_3$. The composition $g \circ f$ is then a bijection from $S_1$ to $S_3$. Thus, we know that $S_1 \sim_\mathrm{bi} S_3$, so the relation is transitive.

By combining the three mini-proofs above, we can conclude that the relation is an equivalence relation.

Also, I was thinking of examples of two distinct equivalence classes. May I know if:

$$
\begin{align}
& [\{1,2\}] =\{\{a,b\} \mid a \in \mathbb{N} \text{ and } b \in \mathbb{N} \setminus a\}, \\[6pt]
& [\{1,2,3\}] = \{\{a,b,c\} \mid a \in \mathbb{N} \mbox{ and } b \in \mathbb{N} \setminus a \text{ and } c \in \mathbb{N} \setminus a \setminus b\}
\end{align}
$$

would suffice?

Hope some one can help me to improve my proof. Thank you!

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: @almagest May I know if my examples of equivalence classes look good?